# How to send listview to Mysql database from button?

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I've been trying to pass the listview data from sqlite to MySQL database.
How to send all item of listview to mysql database ?
I dont know how to get value of listview.
I want mysql database get all item of listview.

This in my Code

```
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection = {OrderContract.OrderEntry._ID,
                OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
                OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_PRICE,
                OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY,
        };
        return new CursorLoader(this, OrderContract.OrderEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    private void addorder(){

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        final String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        final String foliono = "1";
        final String item_code = "";
        final String item_name = "";
        final String qty = "";

        class Addorder extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(SummaryActivity.this,"Add...","Wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(SummaryActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
                HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(settings.KEY_iptv_foliono,foliono);
                params.put(settings.KEY_iptv_item_code,item_code);
                params.put(settings.KEY_iptv_item_name,item_name);
                params.put(settings.KEY_iptv_item_qty,qty);

                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String res = rh.sendPostRequest(settings.URL_ADD, params);
                return res;
            }
        }

        Addorder ae = new Addorder();
        ae.execute();
    }


}
```

This is my adapter for listview

```
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry._ID);
        int name = cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_NAME);
        int priceofdrink = cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_PRICE);
        int quantityofdrink = cursor.getColumnIndex(OrderContract.OrderEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY);

        String nameoffood = cursor.getString(name);
        String pricesoffood = cursor.getString(priceofdrink);
        String quantityfood = cursor.getString(quantityofdrink);
        String idoffood = cursor.getString(id);

        idorder.setText(idoffood);
        drinkName.setText(nameoffood);
        price.setText(currencyFormatter(pricesoffood));
        quantity.setText(quantityfood);

    }

   
}
```

I am trying to get column value from a cursor, but i didnt work
Anyone can help me to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47954360/12709358

Comment: like make a model class ?